# Accessing C drive on another computer over network as admin

Tags: c#, process, cross-domain, credentials

I am attempting to write a simple program that scans all IP's on my subnet and then goes into their C: to check some things out. The only issue I am having is with regards to gaining access rites to the C drive by using the admin credentials (which are on every computer for the domain).

```
Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UserName = "Administrator";
        p.StartInfo.Password = secPw;
        p.StartInfo.Domain = "GREENSAVER.ads";
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "\\\\GS00115\\C$\\users";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.Start();
        string[] filent = Directory.GetDirectories(test);
```

I am positive the secure password I am providing is correct. But when I run this code I get the exception:

system.componentmodel.win32exception access is denied

If I run the process with out using any credentials, I will receive the pop up necessary for me to log in to said host and if I manually enter the credentials there everything works fine and I have access.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `WMI` are you familiar with this.. ? also sounds kind of fishy.. why do you need to check other peoples machines ...perhaps you are being denied for a reason...LOL

Comment: Because I am the office IT and I am trying to compile a list of each computer and their current users for our records... LOL

Comment: then perhaps you need to look at if they have local share setup or the Security policy .. or Remote Access...and to get folder names you can definitely do this using `WMI`

Comment: Currently on a path leading to the remote access. I sh'all keep you postedddd

Answer (score 0):

I found a very cool class:
http://lookfwd.doitforme.gr/blog/media/PinvokeWindowsNetworking.cs

Followed the connectToRemote method, gave me access to the subdirectories no problem at all.

I copied and pasted the entire code they give, rename namespace and start invoking that shiznit in your program.

Thanks MethodMan responses, I feel less lonely now.